# Serialize a array of lists

Tags: c#, list, xmlserializer

So, I have this list:

```
List<PointF>[] VOIGraphics = new List<PointF>[Globals.MaxVOIS + 1];

for (int i = 0; i < VOIGraphics.Length; i++)
{
    VOIGraphics[i] = new List<PointF>();
}
```

And I want to save this list to a .xml file. Here is the code:

```
serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<PointF>[]));
```

The program compiles fine but when I save the list to a .xml file the program crashes on the above line.

Error message:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ut05c.png

Comment: please post the error you are getting.

Comment: How it crashes? Any error you can provide?

Comment: Have you checked that the [Serialized] attribute is on the VOIGraphics class and all sub-objects?

Comment: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: How are you using `serializer`? might you be passing a null value to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well List[] is not exactly an instance but a reference to the first instance and hence an error. You will need to iterate over the array of lists you have and get the type of each ith list or you can use the type of the first element for all lists since it will not change. Below is how I rewrote the code to get it compiled and run. But the XML generated is not what I would want since deserializing it may be an issue. But that will be the next question I guess if you follow this route :)

```
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"Serialized.xml");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_pointList[0].GetType());
        for (int i = 0; i < ListSize; i++)
        {                
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, _pointList[i]);
        }
```

Comment: This code works. Tanks! Can you post the code to deserialize? I am not succeeding :(

Comment: As you can see from the output xml it is not so easy. You may probably have to change your VOIGRAPHICS class.  Or you have to ditch the usage of list serialization and iterate over each pointf instance and serialize that.  Will make a post if i do that.

Comment: Hi fakemeta,  if the code works for serialization,  can you mark that as an answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Well it is not possible to deserialize (at least I do not know of a way) when an array of list is serialized. So I modified some of teh data structures:

```
public class MyPointList
{
    public List<PointF> _listOfPoints;
}
```

Make sure the member is public or give a public GET and SET properties. This is needed by the serializer and deserializer.

Then add another list to hold this list of points - public IList _listOfList.

Here is the serialization code:

```
        TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"Serialized.xml");
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_listOfList.GetType());            
        serializer.Serialize(textWriter, _listOfList);
```

And here comes the deserializer:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(_listOfList.GetType());
        //Geting XMl from the file.
        TextReader tr = new StreamReader(@"Serialized.xml");
        _listOfList = (IList<MyPointList>)serializer.Deserialize(tr);
```

A slight restructuring of the way data is stored makes things a lot easier. Hope this helps.